# WYSIWYG check box is missing for Text field in Strapi

Tags: wysiwyg, strapi

I am using Text field for description text with links but links are not rendering as expected and WYSIWYG is missing from Advanced setting..
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ If you have tried coding a solution that didn't work it would still be useful to add the code to your post. Check out how to produce a Minimal Reproducible Example here >>> stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Now `string`, `text` and `rich text` and separate fields.

You will have tu use `rich text` to have the WYSIWYG.

[image]